# Explanation of spurious result from WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

MySQL 8. I'm seeing a spurious row returned in a query, due to missing specification of table name. I know how to fix it, I'd like to understand why it occurs.

Please see following fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beb1ed/1/0

The purpose is to find any rows in the Scheduled Table that also exist in the Planned table, matched by SubscriptionID and date.

The results returned are:

```
RealWorldVisitDate      CustomerID      SubscriptionID
2019-01-14 00:00:00     5               13  
2019-01-14 00:00:00     17              23
```

However the WHERE clause should limit the results to just the first row (CustomerID 5 / SubscriptionID 13).

**I know the solution** to fix this and return the correct rows is to specify the table in the WHERE as per following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblPlanned WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblScheduled WHERE tblScheduled.SubscriptionID = **tblPlanned.**SubscriptionID AND tblScheduled.DateScheduled = RealWorldVisitDate ) > 0
```

But I want to understand *why* the original query (as per fiddle) returns a spurious row for CustomerID 17 / SubscriptionID 23, seeing as a row with this combo of date and SubscriptionID doesn't exist in tblScheduled. It's clearly to do with the duplicate SubscriptionID column name in the 2 tables, but I can't understand the mysql execution logic that causes it.

(question is deliberately short due to previous complaints about too much detail. Ask me if you need further data etc).

Thank you.

---

Schema and data as per fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblScheduled` (
  `ScheduledTargetID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DateScheduled` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `SubscriptionID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `tblScheduled` (`ScheduledTargetID`, `DateScheduled`, `CustomerID`, `SubscriptionID`) VALUES
(25, '2018-11-19 00:00:00', 16, 15),
(24, '2018-11-19 00:00:00', 17, 23),
(27, '2018-11-23 00:00:00', 5, 1),
(26, '2018-11-23 00:00:00', 14, 18),
(23, '2019-01-14 00:00:00', 5, 13);

CREATE TABLE `tblPlanned` (
  `RealWorldVisitDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `SubscriptionID` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `tblPlanned` (`RealWorldVisitDate`, `CustomerID`, `SubscriptionID`) VALUES
('2019-01-15 00:00:00', 5, 4),
('2019-01-14 00:00:00', 5, 13),
('2019-01-28 00:00:00', 5, 27),
('2019-01-14 00:00:00', 17, 23),
('2019-02-11 00:00:00', 17, 23);


SELECT * FROM tblPlanned WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblScheduled WHERE tblScheduled.SubscriptionID = SubscriptionID AND tblScheduled.DateScheduled = RealWorldVisitDate ) > 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default place MySQL will look for a column in a subquery is the table from which you are querying so

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM tblScheduled
WHERE tblScheduled.SubscriptionID = SubscriptionID AND tblScheduled.DateScheduled = RealWorldVisitDate
```

is effectively the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM tblScheduled
WHERE tblScheduled.SubscriptionID = tblScheduled.SubscriptionID AND tblScheduled.DateScheduled = RealWorldVisitDate
```

which is equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM tblScheduled 
WHERE tblScheduled.DateScheduled = RealWorldVisitDate
```

which explains the result you are getting since the row in `tblScheduled` with `DateScheduled='2019-01-14 00:00:00'` matches two rows in `tblPlanned` (those with `[CustomerID, SubscriptionID]` = `[5,13]` and `[17,23]`).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Obvious when you see it! My confusion was the legitimate CustomerID 5 / SubscriptionID 13 row, which has the same date and should be in the results, but I went down the blind alley of assuming the WHERE was correct for row 1 and incorrect for row 2 - when in fact it was incorrect for both, but just happened to return the correct row 1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> "find any rows in the Scheduled Table that also exist in the Planned
>   table"

This is precisely what an [INNER JOIN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm) is for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPlanned 
INNER JOIN tblScheduled 
  ON tblScheduled.SubscriptionID = tblPlanned.SubscriptionID 
  AND tblScheduled.DateScheduled = tblPlanned.RealWorldVisitDate;
```

This is much clearer and a more efficient way to match the rows, it's the standard thing to do in SQL in this kind of scenario.

Your original attempt was flawed partly by not using this approach, but also because of the ambiguity over which SubscriptionID field to use in the subquery - by default it matches to the table in the subquery, so you're just getting results where the field matches itself.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is possible, but is a JOIN more efficient than a WHERE?

Comment: It's very likely to be more efficient than a subquery, yes. JOIN is intended for this kind of work, removing the need for awkward subqueries.

Comment: Great, thank you. The joys of a limited test data set :-)